# Need help with cipher

Tags: cipher

I've been attempting to solve a coded message that someone posted to [Twitter](https://twitter.com/planetemerson/status/1548073221081026561), but I can't crack it. I'm not even sure what kind of cipher it is. I believe it needs a key to be solved, but I'm not sure what the key would be either. The code is as follows:

ZTTAMABCDUUGMFFCQLCSVEPQI

COFLEMASPTEYBECTEMASPDYFBABPZ

On metavox.codes, there are 9 multiple choice questions that, if answered correctly, will unlock a hidden voice line. This particular cipher pertains to question #6. The clues should indicate that one of the choices listed below is correct.

[image: The clues should indicate that one of the choices listed here is correct.]

The choices are as follows:

- A Queen of Spades > 3 of Hearts
- B Queen of Hearts > 10 of Clubs
- C 4 of Spades > 5 of Hearts > 6 of Diamonds
- D 9 of Diamonds > 7 of Hearts
- E Ace of Spades > 8 of Clubs
- F King of Diamonds > 10 of Clubs
- G 4 of Clubs > Ace of Spades
- H 2 of Diamonds > Ace of Diamonds
- I Jack of Clubs > King of Diamonds
- J 7 of Clubs > Ace of Spades > 8 of Hearts

It's worth noting that, each time the page is loaded, the order of answers change.

I've been at this for a few days, so believe me when I say that coming here is a last resort. I figured it's a Vigenère cipher, but again, with no key, solving it would be impossible.

Comment: So the puzzle relates to the game Resident Evil 6, but I'm not sure how much knowledge of the game is required. I took the audio in the clue and reversed it, able to faintly make out a voice saying something that sounds like "twenty-three", but I could be wrong.